# Coagulation of blood in small intestine due to trypsin

Tags: human-physiology, red-blood-cell

Trypsin is secreted in the small intestine to convert proteins into dipeptides i.e. to carry out digestion of proteins. However, it is also a coagulating agent which coagulates blood by hydrolysing fibrinogen into fibrin. My question is, why doesn't the blood in the small intestine coagulate?

Comment: Remember trypsin is an intraluminal enzyme, and is not normally in contact with blood.